# I am confused over why we use Application Server when Spring and Tomcat provide all features of Application Server?

Tags: server

I am confused over why we use Application Server when Spring and Tomcat provide all features of Application Server?
I am looking for the job i have accounting application project in resume developed on Spring MVC and Tomcat, in last interview interviewer asked me why you are not using Application server which i unable to answered.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat can also be used as application server but it does not have all the application server capabilities. For a simple web application, Tomcat can be used.